# Why can't I access the administrative drive shares on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, smb

I am not able to access the administrative drive shares (such as `\\192.168.1.4\c$` or `\\192.168.1.4\e$`) on Windows Server 2008 R2, even if I'm logged in as a user who is part of the Administrators group.

I can only access those shares if I use the built in Administrator account.  How can I configure the server to allow any administrator to access the administrative drive shares, like I can on Windows Server 2003?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the fix:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947232

Comment: This is useful when using psexec and specifying a user context.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 2008 is more locked down then Windows 2003. I believe that the admin shares are *only* accessible to the "true" local admin user. To give similar access to other users you will need to create a new share that gives those users that access.

The may be one of the security changes between 2003 and 2008 that is reverted if you turn off UAC, though I have not tried this myself.

Comment: ok, I was worried about this :(